# NS-3: Create a Bottleneck Link

Tags: tcp, network-programming, simulation, topology, ns-3

I have a client and a server, both running the Multipath TCP stack. Multiple point to point links are created between them, I want the links to share a bottleneck link before reaching the server. I looked [here](https://www.nsnam.org/doxygen/codel-vs-droptail-basic-test_8cc_source.html), but the situation is less complex than mine.

Below is the code that runs MPTCP. Could you suggest how should I make the changes to create the required topology. I am a bit confused on this. Thanks a lot for your help.

Here is the code for Topology that I have.

```
NodeContainer nodes;
nodes.Create(2);
client = nodes.Get(0);
server = nodes.Get(1);

MpInternetStackHelper stack;
stack.Install(client); stack.Install(server);

vector<Ipv4InterfaceContainer> ipv4Ints;
for(int i=0; i < sf; i++)
{
    PointToPointHelper p2plink;
    p2plink.SetDeviceAttribute ("DataRate", StringValue("5Mbps"));
    p2plink.SetChannelAttribute("Delay", StringValue("100ms"));

    NetDeviceContainer netDevices;
    netDevices = p2plink.Install(nodes);

    std::stringstream netAddr;
    netAddr << "10.1." << (i+1) << ".0";
    string str = netAddr.str();

    Ipv4AddressHelper ipv4addr;
    ipv4addr.SetBase(str.c_str(), "255.255.255.0");
    Ipv4InterfaceContainer interface = ipv4addr.Assign(netDevices);
    ipv4Ints.insert(ipv4Ints.end(), interface);
}
```